# PHP Solr never returning found documents

Tags: php, solr, tomcat6

I am trying to find documents I have in my solr instance through php. When I go to my solr admin and do a search I get the following:

```
  <response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
    <int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">443</int><lst name="params">
<str name="indent">on</str><str name="start">0</str>
<str name="q">*:*</str><str name="rows">10</str>
<str name="version">2.2</str></lst></lst>
<result name="response" numFound="4" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="description">An Aweomse dish</str>
<arr name="ingredients"><str>Radish</str><str>Beans</str><str>Curry</str></arr>
<str name="name">Alfredo Chehse</str>
<str name="recipe_id">10</str><str name="thumbnail">123343f342</str>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="description">An Aweomse dish</str>
<arr name="ingredients"><str>Radish</str><str>Beans</str>
<str>Curry</str></arr><str name="name">Alfredo Chehse</str>
<str name="recipe_id">11</str><str name="thumbnail">123343f342</str>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

So I know the data is in there. Now in my PHP I have this:

```
$query = new SolrQuery();

        $query->setQuery('Radish');

        $query->setStart(0);

        $query->setRows(50);

        $query->addField('ingredients') -> addField('name');

        $query_response = $client->query($query);

        $query_response->setParseMode(SolrQueryResponse::PARSE_SOLR_DOC);

        $response = $query_response->getResponse();

        print_r($response);
```

But I alway get an empty result set:

SolrObject Object
(

```
 [responseHeader] => SolrObject Object
        (
            [status] => 0
            [QTime] => 1
            [params] => SolrObject Object
                (
                    [fl] => ingredients,name
                    [indent] => on
                    [start] => 0
                    [q] => radish
                    [wt] => xml
                    [rows] => 50
                    [version] => 2.2
                )

        )

    [response] => SolrObject Object
        (
            [numFound] => 0
            [start] => 0
            [docs] => 
        )
```

My question is why is my results always empty no matter what I search for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is **ingredients** an indexed field?

Do you have a case insensitive fulltext index field for each document?

Try this

```
$query->setQuery('ingredients:*Radish*');
```

Comment: Ingredients in schema: <field name="ingredients" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

Comment: Bingo! That did it! I'm guessing I should change the field type

Comment: Then it must return a result for **$query->setQuery('ingredients:*Radish*');**

Comment: Oh, good :) No you don't have to change that field. It is indexed and correct. But what you may want to have is a full-text index field which will have all the text in your document as lower cased so that in future you can search for any text in the full-text field like **q=+text:something**